# Trying to set ng-class according to function result

Tags: angularjs, class, ng-class

I have a function that returns true when I issue some kind of words. This function is correct and verified, however I can't bring its result on the view:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': ctrl.currentPage('parceiro')}"><a class="waves-effect waves-orange" href="parceiro.php"><i class="flaticon-college"></i>Seu Perfil</a></li>
```

For `ctrl.currentPage('parceiro')`, the result is `true` (tested with console.log). Any ideas?

Edit: the DOM is displayed as `<li ng-class="{'active': ctrl.currentPage('parceiro')}"><a class="waves-effect waves-orange" href="parceiro.php"><i class="flaticon-college"></i>Seu Perfil</a></li>`, `{'active': ctrl.currentPage('parceiro')}` isn't being "compiled" ?

Also, the function I'm testing is

```
currentPage = function(name){
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: are you returning value from `ctrl.currentPage = function(item){//other code here; return true/false; }`

Comment: Yes, the function returns true.

Comment: maybe you didn't define 'active' on your css.

Comment: does `currentPage` function binded to controller `this` context, like it should be either `this.currentPage` or `ctrl.currentPage` ..

Comment: I was using the wrong bind inside the controller, now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to set `this` to `ctrl` inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you [got it all sorted out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545819/trying-to-set-ng-class-according-to-function-result/31546065#31546065), but wanted to provide some code example context for future reference.

The below snippet is a working example using your code as a base.

```js
function SimpleCtrl(){}
SimpleCtrl.prototype = {
  currentPage:'',
  setCurrentPage:function(val){
    console.log({name:'currentPage', val:val, result:this.currentPage === val});
    return this.currentPage === val;
  }
};

angular.module('so-app', [])
  .controller('simpleCtrl', SimpleCtrl);
```

```css
.active {
  border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="so-app" ng-controller="simpleCtrl as ctrl">
  <br />
  <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.currentPage = 'parceiro'">Set Page = 'parceiro'</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.currentPage = ''">Clear</button>
  <br />
  <h3>{{ctrl.currentPage}}</h3>
  <br />
  <br />
  <li ng-class="{'active': ctrl.setCurrentPage('parceiro')}"><a class="waves-effect waves-orange" href="parceiro.php"><i class="flaticon-college"></i>Seu Perfil</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your Code is perfect but ng-class statement is wrong. so use correct way

```
`<li ng-class="({active: ctrl.currentPage('parceiro')})"><a class="waves-effect waves-orange" href="parceiro.php"><i class="flaticon-college"></i>Seu Perfil</a></li>`
```